# If $A$ is positive real symmetric matrix and $B$ is real symmetric, does there exist some $V$ such that $V^{T}AV$=$I$ and $V^TBV$ is diagonal matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, diagonalization, symmetric-matrices

Let's say we have two matrices $A$ (a positive real symmetric matrix) and $B$ (a real symmetric matrix). And let us suppose that in general $A$ and $B$ don't commute with each other. Then,

Q. Is it possible to have a transformation matrix $V$ such that $V^{T}AV$=$I$ and $V^TBV$ is diagonal? Please provide proof.

I can see that one can find an orthogonal transformation such that it diagonalizes (but doesn't make it unit matrix $I$) $A$ (as it is a symmetric matrix) but it will not always diagonalize $B$. Is it even possible to find such a transformation $V$?

Comment: @Tim, I need a transformation $V$ here that makes both $A$ and $B$ diagonal. Yes $B$ is orthogonally diagonalizable and of course, $V^TBV$ is symmetric but what I need is $V$ which simultaneously diagonalizes $A$ (making it $I$) and $B$.

Comment: @Tim, please read the question, I need a single transformation $V$ which simultaneously makes $V^TAV=I$ and $V^TBV=$ a diagonal matrix.

Comment: This should be easy. Consider $V=A^{-1/2}Q$ for some appropriate orthogonal matrix $Q$.

Comment: @user1551, Can you please elaborate? And if possible write an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Let  $A = S^TS$ and $R=S^{-1}$. Since $R^TBR$ is real symmetric matrix you can find $U$ is an orthogonal matrix  such that
$U^TR^TBRU=\Gamma$ where $\Gamma$ is a diagonal matrix?

Let $V = RU$ can you finish the proof?

Comment: How can I write $A=S^TS$ for any positive real symmetric matrix?

Comment: Do you know a square root of positive matrix?

Comment: no I don't know.

Comment: Just google it and you will have how to have $S$